# Flask returns 404 error when trying to connect via localhost

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, flask, http-status-code-404

I am trying to build a Python Flask application, but I cannot access it. Flask recognizes the  request, but for some reason doesn't execute the function. Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

app.route("/")
def main_page():
    print("main_page() was called")
    return render_template("main_page.html")
```

I am currently running it by typing `flask run` the Windows CMD. The GET request is detected, but `main_page` is not called and 404 is returned.

`127.0.0.1 - - [01/Apr/2022 18:07:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed '@' in app.route, it should be

```
@app.route('/')
```

Few points, you can try debug mode, not sure with flask run. By adding main method

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried below command
**python file.py runserver -d**

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I could be such an idiot not to spot it myself.

Comment: sheesh, that 1 char you forget, thanks!